# PGSQLSimpleException: Connection Error: io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException: DefaultChannelPromise

Tags: java, postgresql, pgjdbc-ng

I am using com.impossibl.pgjdbc-ng package to listen to postgres channel which notifies on every insert/update of a table.

My java code is :

```
PGDataSource dataSource1 = new PGDataSource();
// credentials

PGDataSource dataSource2 = new PGDataSource();
// credentails

PGNotificationListener listener = new PGNotificationListener() {
    @Override
    public void notification(int processId, java.lang.String channelName, java.lang.String payload) {
        System.out.println(payload);

        try (PGConnection connection2 = (PGConnection) dataSource2.getConnection()) {
            
            //update database2

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

 try (PGConnection connection1 = (PGConnection) dataSource1.getConnection()) {
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.execute("LISTEN my_channel_name");
    statement.close();
    connection.addNotificationListener(listener);
    
    // infinite loop to keep connection active
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

Code is working and I am able to listen to the notices on the channel but I am encountering the following error very frequently

```
com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGSQLSimpleException: Connection Error: io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException: DefaultChannelPromise@78b0832e(incomplete)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.ErrorUtils.makeSQLException(ErrorUtils.java:138)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.ConnectionUtil.createConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:326)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.AbstractDataSource.createConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:125)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource.getConnection(PGDataSource.java:71)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource.getConnection(PGDataSource.java:63)
    at nic.oad.AttendanceReconciliation.service.LeaveReconciliation$1.notification(LeaveReconciliation.java:73)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDirectConnection.reportNotification(PGDirectConnection.java:1514)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDirectConnection.connectionNotificationReceived(PGDirectConnection.java:1448)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.system.BasicContext$ServerConnectionListener.notificationReceived(BasicContext.java:133)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ServerConnectionFactory$DefaultHandler.notification(ServerConnectionFactory.java:556)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.MessageDispatchHandler.receiveNotification(MessageDispatchHandler.java:417)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.MessageDispatchHandler.parseAndDispatch(MessageDispatchHandler.java:307)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.MessageDispatchHandler.dispatch(MessageDispatchHandler.java:221)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.MessageDispatchHandler.channelRead(MessageDispatchHandler.java:152)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:426)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:682)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:617)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:534)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException: DefaultChannelPromise@78b0832e(incomplete)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ServerConnectionFactory.translateConnectionException(ServerConnectionFactory.java:493)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ServerConnectionFactory.connect(ServerConnectionFactory.java:251)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ServerConnectionFactory.connect(ServerConnectionFactory.java:143)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ServerConnectionFactory.connect(ServerConnectionFactory.java:124)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.system.BasicContext.<init>(BasicContext.java:213)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDirectConnection.<init>(PGDirectConnection.java:236)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.ConnectionUtil.createConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:317)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException: DefaultChannelPromise@78b0832e(incomplete)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.checkDeadLock(DefaultPromise.java:386)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.checkDeadLock(DefaultChannelPromise.java:159)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultPromise.java:236)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultChannelPromise.java:137)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.syncUninterruptibly(DefaultPromise.java:335)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.syncUninterruptibly(DefaultChannelPromise.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.syncUninterruptibly(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ServerConnectionFactory.connect(ServerConnectionFactory.java:153)
    ... 39 more
```

Anyone please suggest how to resolve this issue.